# C# httpwebrequest is only sending GET requests even when method is set to POST

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I'm using Xamarin C# and php to create a simple android app that sends coordinate data to an apache sql database. When I use httpwebrequest to send a POST request to the server php, it sends a GET instead. Even though I set the request type to POST. The strange thing is that other requests that I have used using the exact same code work okay, this one specifically isn't working.

```
public class gpsGetterScript{

public static double longitude;
public static double latitude;
public static SimpleLocationManager locationManager =  new SimpleLocationManager();


public static void startGetLocation()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 6 * 1000;

    void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        double lon = locationManager.LastLocation.Longitude;
        double lat = locationManager.LastLocation.Latitude;
        longitude = lon;
        latitude = lat;
        Console.WriteLine(lon.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(lat.ToString());

        Dictionary<string, string> gpsData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        gpsData.Add("longitude", lon.ToString());
        gpsData.Add("latitude", lat.ToString());
        gpsData.Add("device_owner", "Test");

        var url = "theURL";

        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";

        var contentType = "application/json";
        //var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        httpRequest.ContentType = contentType;

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gpsData);
        //var data = "longitude=" + lon.ToString() + "&latitude=" + lat.ToString() + "&device_owner=" + "Test";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(httpRequest.RequestUri.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(httpRequest.Headers);
            Console.WriteLine(httpRequest.Method);
            streamWriter.Write(data);
        }
        
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Start();
    locationManager.StartLocationUpdates(LocationAccuracy.Balanced, 5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(.5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    SimpleLocationLogger.Enabled = true;
}
```

}

here is one of the httprequests from a related project that does work (same server being used)

```
public static string sendLoginRequest(string email, string password)
    {
        var url = "theURL";

        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";

        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(data);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I know it is the app sending the wrong request, as when I made the php echo the request type it came back as GET. Strangely, when I use reqbin to make the POST request using the same URL, it works fine. It really is just for some reason the request in C# is not sending a POST. The other question about this was resolved by adding a www. to the api url, but that did not work for me.

UPDATE: 4/20/2022- Here is the php code

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once '../../../Database.php';
include_once '../location_obj.php';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $item = new location_obj($db);
    $stmt = $item->InputCoordinates();

    $item->longitude = $data->longitude;
    $item->latitude = $data->latitude;
    $item->device_owner = $data->device_owner;

    if ($item->InputCoordinates()) {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Successfully", "data" => $item, "Request Type" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "failed! Check your data and try again.", "data" => $item, "Request Type" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));
    }
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "Only the POST method is supported!", "Request Type" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));
}

?>`
```

I get the error `{"error":"Only the POST method is supported!","Request Type":"GET"}` but when I use reqbin I get `"message": "Successfully", "data": { "longitude": "theLongitude", "latitude": "theLatitude", "device_owner": "Test" }, "Request Type": "POST"`
I checked the url that is used using `Console.WriteLine(url);` , it is the right one.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check if the correct code is executed ? Did you observe the value of  `url`? Do you get 404 error ? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: @Chetan I updated my post with answers to your last two questions. To the first, I do check a lot with the `Console.Writeline()` debug command, but if you mean some other type of debugging, i'm not sure, i'm still fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, seems I forgot to add a / at the end of the URL. It was https://example.com/api/v2/location/input instead of https://example.com/api/v2/location/input/

Comment: The links are identical.